# Does any of C++ smart pointers avoid data race in strict sense?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, race-condition

For consumer/producer model there is a built-in mechanism to avoid data race - queue.

But for global flag there seems not yet a ready-to-go type to avoid data race rather than attaching a mutex to each global flag as simple as boolean or int type.

I came across shared pointer. Is it true that as one pointer operates on that variable, another is prohibited from accessing it?

Or will unique pointer promise no data race?

e.g. scenario:

One thread updates the number of visits on serving a new visitor, while another thread periodically reads that number out (might be copy behavior) and save it to log. They will be accessing the same memory on the heap that stores that number, and race condition is that they are accessing it at the same time from different cpu cores, which would cause a crash.

Comment: [std::atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)?

Comment: A smart pointer prevents data race from accessing _the pointer_ (I mean, by deallocating data when last user is done with it), not data the pointer points to.

Comment: `auto& pointee = *some_smart_pointer;` now the caller can do what they like to `pointee` and the smart pointer can do nothing about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For consumer/producer model there is a built-in mechanism to avoid data race - queue.

The standard library has no thread-safe queue. `std::queue` and others cannot be used without explicit synchronization in multiple threads.

> I came across shared pointer. Is it true that as one pointer operates on that variable, another is prohibited from accessing it?

`std::shared_ptr` (or any other standard library smart pointer) does not in any way prevent multiple threads accessing the managed object unsynchronized. `std::shared_ptr` only guarantees that destruction of the managed object is thread-safe.

> Or will unique pointer promise no data race?

`std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied, so you cannot have multiple `std::unique_ptr` or threads managing the object. None of the smart pointers guarantee that access to the smart pointer object itself is free of data races.

> One thread updates the number of visits on serving a new visitor, while another thread periodically reads that number out (might be copy behavior) and save it to log. They will be accessing the same memory on the heap that stores that number, and race condition is that they are accessing it at the same time from different cpu cores, which would cause a crash.

That can simply be a `std::atomic<int>` or similar. Unsynchronized access to a `std::atomic` is allowed. There can of course still be race conditions if you rely on a particular order in which the access should happen, but in your example that doesn't seem to be the case. However, in contrast to non-atomic objects, there will be at least no undefined behavior due to the unsynchronized access (*data race*).

Comment: But I heard that `std::queue` has already employed `mutex`

Comment: @GeorgeY That's plain wrong.

Comment: So is there any solution to protect such a data structure? Like one thread adds to a vector while another pops it out under the First In First Out principle?

Comment: @GeorgeY You either use a mutex to protect access to the `std::vector`/`std::queue` or write/use a library which implements a thread-safe queue.